# React material UI form validation using error and helperText

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have created a form on which I want to validate the inputs and I saw the **material UI** have an attribute called `error` boleean and another attribute called `helperText` for `TextField` input of the form but I didn't found nothing about how to inject that error on element when the validation conditon is not fulfiled
[image]
here is my code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-hip84?file=/demo.js:1020-1055

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({ name: "", email: "", remember: "" });

  const onChange = i => {
    setForm({ ...form, [i.target.name]: i.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(form);
    e.target.reset();
  };

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Grid container spacing={4}>
        {Object.keys(form).map((objKey, idx) => {
          return (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={idx}>
              <TextField
                error
                helperText="No Value added in this field"
                id={`input${idx}`}
                label={objKey}
                name={objKey}
                fullWidth={true}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the `error` prop of the `TextField` you will need to manage the errors on your own (just like you manage the value for your fields).

To do that - the value of `error` should not be fixed, but should be true/false, based on some calculation that you are doing.

I used your code to do the checking if the value (for each field) equals specific value. This is **not** a real-life example, and you probably want to change this to some kind of a regex check, but this should give you a good starting point:

```
export default function SubmitForm() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [form, setForm] = useState({ name: "aaa", email: "bbb", remember: "ccc" });
  const isValidData = {name: "aaa", email: "bbb", remember: "ccc"};

  ...

  const checkIsValid = (fieldName, value) => {
    // Here you probably what to check this to some regex validation
    if (isValidData[fieldName] === value) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  return (
        ...
        {Object.keys(form).map((objKey, idx) => {
          return (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={idx}>
              <TextField
                error={!checkIsValid(objKey, form[objKey])}
                ...
              />
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
  );
}
```

To see the complete working example please check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-textfield-control-errors-z0tfo?file=/demo.js

Comment: that is cool, thank you. And if I want to validate forms elements onSubmit form I guess I need to call "checkIsValid" on submit form button, right ?

Comment: Yes, thats correct :) I gave you an example of "live validation". You could change this to happen only "on submit". Keep in mind that if you do this only "on submit" you will probably need to have another variable that will save the value of the validation status for each field.